# How to make a navbar fully disappear with bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2, navbar

I am using Vue.js and Bootstrap 4. I would like to make the navbar fully disappeared when the screen becomes small.

Thi is my Bootstrap 4 code in a .vue file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <p class="pl-5">Hello Guest</p>
            <p class="mr-5">Nice play!</p>
        </nav>
    </div>
</template>

<script>  
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                title: "Vue ninjas"
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    p {
        color: lightgreen;
        text-align: center;
    }
    nav {
        height: 11vh;
    }
</style>
```

Obviously I don't want that the navbar becomes a dropdown menu but I would like it disappears with all the content on resizing. I tried in many ways with no success. Is there a way to do that with Bootstrap 4 or Javascript? Can help?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: you can write media queries for that like if screen size is { your required size after which it would disappear } then apply css style display: none to navbar class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code:

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
        nav { 
            display:none 
        }
    }
```